# Is there a way to store data obtained using selenium into a database provided by django?

Tags: python, django

I want to store data obtained using selenium into a database provided by django.

But I can't. Please tell me how to solve.

The code below is my code.

My project name is 'ebookranking' and app name is 'index'

---

```
#kyobo.py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ebookranking.settings')
import django
django.setup()
from index.models import Book

def kyobo():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\insutance\\PycharmProjects\\chromedriver')  
    driver.get('http://m.kyobobook.co.kr/digital/ebook/bestList.ink?cate_code=1&class_code=&barcode=&barcodes=&cate_gubun=&orderClick=&listCateGubun=1&listSortType=1&listSortType2=0&listSortType3=0&listSortType4=0&need_login=N&type=&returnUrl=%2Fdigital%2Febook%2FbestList.ink&reviewLimit=0&refererUrl=&barcodes_temp=&gubun=&ser_product_yn=&groupSort=1&groupSort2=0&groupSort3=0&groupSort4=0')
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)       

    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    titles = []     

    for n in range(1,31):
        title = soup.select_one('#list > li:nth-child('+ str(n) +') > div.detail > p.pubTitle > a')              
        titles.append(title.text)              

    driver.quit()

    return titles

    if __name__=='__main__':
        datas = kyobo()
        for t in datas:
            Book(title=t).save()
```

---

The code below is my models code.

---

```
#models.py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    price = models.CharField(max_length = 10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `django.setup()` as per [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage)

> After you’ve either set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or called configure(),
>   you’ll need to call django.setup() to load your settings and populate
>   Django’s application registry. For example:
>
> ```
> import django
> from django.conf import settings
> from myapp import myapp_defaults
>
> settings.configure(default_settings=myapp_defaults, DEBUG=True)
> django.setup()
>
> # Now this script or any imported module can use any part of Django it needs.
> from myapp import models
> ```

Comment: In line 6, After setting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE, I called `django.setup()`


Static sites can be crawled using requests, but Site I want to crawl is the javascripts website.

Comment: I couldn't indent `if __name__=='__main__':` , but I did it.

By not indenting that part, I solved the problem.

Thank you for your help